# Use a select option as variable further down the same form in laravel

Tags: laravel

I try to get the selected *option* for the Team select on my *form* to further use it in the same form to limit the available positions in the selected team.
I managed to limit each team, so that it has a maximum of 9 players.
The idea is to have +-2 players on each position( 2 forward, 2 center, 2 back, 3 substitutes) for each team, if the spots are full the 'position' (ex. *forward*) option doesn't show up for the selected team.
Might be helpful : I am using foreign keys : (player -> one position_id, team -> many players)
My positions table is consisted of **id, name and max** and it is passed as **$positions**
I am trying to figure out a way, i am new to the subject so if you guys can help me, would be a great.
Or tell me if it isn't possible.

Thanks in advance.

````php
 <form action="/player" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-control">
                @csrf
                ...
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <select name="team_id">
                        <option selected>Select Team</option>
                        @foreach ($teams as $team)
                            @if ($team->players->count() < 9)
                                <option value="{{ $team->id }}">{{ $team->name }}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <select name="position_id">
                        <option selected>Select Position</option>
                        @foreach ($teams as $team)
                            @if ($team->id == ???)
                                @foreach ($positions as $position)
                                    @if ($position->count() > $position->max)
                                        <option value="{{ $position->id }}" disabled>{{ $position->name }}</option>
                                    @else
                                        <option value="{{ $position->id }}">{{ $position->name }}</option>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                ...
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
            </form>
    ```
````

Comment: Are you looking for this to work just on a) only the first render, or b) did you need it to update when the select field is updated? If your answer is b then you need to look into using Laravel Livewire, AlpineJS, Vue, React, or another client-side language that can respond to your select fields onchange event.

Comment: @Azeame Only the first render should be enough, since it's a training project. But i'm further looking into livewire for future uses thanks.